# Could I pull data from firebase with other js file which I didn't used to login?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

Suppose I have a login page for which there's a js file where I used `signInWithEmailAndPassword` method to login and after login different html file opens. So my doubt is that if we could pull data from firebase database from other js file or we have to do that withing the same js file which we used to login ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're asking if the user is still authenticated after navigating away, yes, that is still the case.  You just to [add an authentication state listener](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user) on the pages where you expect the user to be authenticated, and only access the database after that listener indicates that the user is present.

Comment: So do I have to `initializeApp` in every js file where I have to do some operations ?

Comment: And could I store tokens in cookie and access them using any js file later on ?

Comment: You have to initialize Firebase on each new page load.  If you're having problems with additional code you've written, please post another question with the code and explain how it doesn't work the way you expect.

Comment: If the answer was helpful with respect to the question originally asked, please upvote and mark as correct.

Comment: My upvote is not reflected as I don't have sufficient reputation and I can't even answer to others questions...so could you help me with that.

Comment: If you think my question was valid then you could upvote that too.